# Can we detect if the action center is active in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Windows Phone applications are in an unidentified state when the action center is active (When we drag down the shutter).

Can we detect if the action center where the notifications are listed is active while our app is running.

Objective: In such a scenario the application is to be locked

Answer (score 0):

Well Yes You can detect the Action center where the notifications are listed is active as background tasks.Here is [Link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/change-notification-settings) Which Helps you to solve your issue.

If you are not searching for this then you can question to Microsoft Directly on 
[Microsoft Developer Network Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home)

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: Hi Ashman, I am trying to detect if the action center is pulled down (activated) while in debugging mode. 

Do you think the same is possible ?